# Using variables for referencing tables in code

Tags: php, mysql

I need to know the better approach in the following two approaches

1) Use the variable name to refer a table in code/scripts.

2) Directly refer the table name in scripts.

R/
Param

Comment: I do not understand what you want...

Comment: There is no "better approach". Do whatever suits you better

Answer (score 0):

I think you care about that because you think you might need to rename a table some times? Why to do that? What if you will then not like the variable name? :)

Also, wisely chosen identifiers can usually be changed by using plain text Find/Replace.